# c# excel addin, Range.Find loop issue

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015

I am making an excel add-in and one of the pieces is that I am building a custom class list of ranges where there is a specific value in cell. So basically I want to find all cells with the word `"Action=>"` in it. Anyway, I am using basically the same exact code as MSDN lists for looping through a Range.find however, I am having a weird issue.

When I run the first `resultActionCurrentRange = colRange.Find(etc.)` it gives me back the first instance, cell 1,1. Then, when it goes into the while loop, the `colRange.FindNext` does what I expect and finds the next instance, cell 1,18. But for some reason it loops again and goes back to find 1,1 again! So I end up with 3 ranges in my list, instead of just the 2 I want. It is like looping forward, and then back.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you,

```
Excel.Workbook activeWorkBook =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet activeWorkSheet = activeWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range colRange = activeWorkSheet.Columns["A:A"];
Excel.Range resultActionFirstRange = null;
Excel.Range resultActionCurrentRange = null;
List<Excel.Range> ActionRangeList = new List<Excel.Range>();

string searchActionLabel = "Action=>";
string searchDBLabel = "DatabaseName=>";
string searchTblLabel = "TableName=>";

resultActionCurrentRange = colRange.Find(searchActionLabel, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


//get action
while (resultActionCurrentRange != null)
{
    if (resultActionFirstRange == null)
    {
        resultActionFirstRange = resultActionCurrentRange;
        ActionRangeList.Add(resultActionFirstRange);
    }

    else if (resultActionCurrentRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) == resultActionFirstRange.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
    {
        break;
    }

    resultActionCurrentRange = colRange.FindNext(resultActionCurrentRange);
    ActionRangeList.Add(resultActionCurrentRange);
    MessageBox.Show("Range is:" + resultActionCurrentRange.Column.ToString() + resultActionCurrentRange.Row.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Range list count is: " + ActionRangeList.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Oh ok Yeah I see that now. I put in a 2nd if clause to check before adding it to the list. That seemed to work. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong - it is the documented behaviour. See the remarks here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.findnext.aspx

As explained in the documentation, FindNext will loop back at the end of the column & start searching from the top. What you need to do is save the range of the result of the first find & compare to subsequent results from FindNext - when you get a match you stop as you have looped back to the initial position.